# Convert code to generate hash from CryptoJS to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, cryptojs

I want to convert this JS code to C# to use it in an ASP.NET app.

JavaScript code:

```js
var to_md5 = "Some Text Here"
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(CryptoJS.MD5(to_md5.toUpperCase()).toString());
var result = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
console.log(result);
```

I tried the following in C#:

```cs
var to_md5 = "Some Text Here".ToUpper();
var hashString = gSHA1(gMD5(to_md5));

private string gMD5(string input)
{
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    Byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    Byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

private string gSHA1(string s)
{
    Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    Byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);
    return HexStringFromBytes(hashBytes);
}

private string HexStringFromBytes(Byte[] bytes)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        var hex = b.ToString("x2");
        sb.Append(hex);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The results in both cases are different, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: One thing I noted right away that differs, in your Javascript you call `to_md5.toUpperCase()`, but in your C# code you don't set the text as uppercase before passing it to the MD5 hash.

Comment: `hash[i].ToString("X2")` will return upper case hex strings, but `CryptoJS.WordArray.toString()` will [return lower case hex strings](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-hashing-output). Try `ToString("x2")`.

Comment: Why do you want to re-use this code anyway? It seems weird to hash with MD5 then turn the result into a string and hash it again with SHA1. Do you really have to generate the hashes in the same way?

Comment: Apply `HexStringFromBytes()` in `gMD5()` (analogous to `gSHA1()`), as this uses lowercase letters (in contrast to the current hex encoding in `gMD5()`).  This solves the hex enocding issue (and is also neater).

Comment: In addition to the inconsistencies already mentioned: The encodings also differ. CryptoJS uses UTF-8 by default when hashing if the message is passed as string. Therefore, the encoding in `gMD5()` must be changed from ASCII to UTF-8 (otherwise the hashes will be different when the encoded data differ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues in the code. As already stated in the comments, having a *well-known* encoding is important, as well consistent casing. One can get away with that in many cases, but a hash function will produce unexpected results. Additionally, note that the .NET crypto classes usually [implement `IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm?view=net-8.0), so need to be instantiated alongside appropriate `using` statements (or cleaned up manually), if you don't want to risk memory/resource leaks.

Finally, a note regarding **correct use of crypto:** MD5 and SHA1 are both no longer considered state-of-the-art, and should only be used for compatibility with legacy applications. Chaining them does not provide some magic security guarantee. Additionally, as mentioned before, chaining two hash functions with a flaky byte-hex-byte conversion in between is dangerous and may lead to unexpected errors or even security issues. It is better to stick to raw bytes arrays when passing around stuff between cryptographic primitives.

If this is a new project and not a port of an old legacy application, I'd recommend to use a modern hash function like SHA2 or SHA3, and refrain from manual hash chaining, even if this is not security-related code.

For the sake of completeness, the fixed program:

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

var toMd5 = "Some Text Here".ToUpper();
var hashString = ComputeSHA1(ComputeMD5(toMd5));
Console.WriteLine(hashString);

string ComputeMD5(string input)
{
    using var md5 = MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    return HexStringFromBytes(hash);
}

string ComputeSHA1(string input)
{
    using var sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
    
    return HexStringFromBytes(hash);
}

string HexStringFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in bytes) 
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

...which outputs the same hash value as the JavaScript code:

```
6a2b72d89102c35d34bd2981a3a863b18e647da8
```

Comment: We are trying to integrate with a payment gateway that has the hash generated in JS, so we need to work with their way of doing things!.

Comment: Your code is very good, the two main issues that led to different hash were: 1- the ASCII and 2- the X2 in capital letters. we've implemented your code and it is working just fine, thanks